# Deploy de projeto Rails no AWS, acesso sem utilizar porta

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, amazon-aws, deploy

Estou precisando subir um site desenvolvido em *Rails* no *AWS*. Porém, sempre que dou o start ele só fica acessível se eu especificar a porta utilizada pelo Rails

> (www.dominio.com:3000, por exemplo).

Já tentei solucionar isto indo nas configurações de balance do AWS, mas não tive sucesso.

Alguém poderia me dar um direcionamento quanto o que posso fazer para solucionar tal problema?

Answer (score 0):

Se estiver utilizando o rails 5 altere a porta dentro do arquivo `config/puma.rb`.

Mas me parece que você está querendo colocar em produção uma aplicação feita em Rails, e está confundindo o ambiente de desemvolvimento (que roda na porta 3000 por padrão) com ambiente de produção.

Não estou familiarizado com AWS, mas acredito que você precise configurar uma instância no Amazon, depois configurar seu stack de aplição (servidor web, banco de dados, etc)

Espero ter ajudado